# php - making calculations for every combination in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this array with teams that are in a competition, now i want to do some calculations for each match that is going to happen.

```
Array
(
    [Team1] => Array
        (
            [totalHomeGoals] => 48
            [totalHomeAgainstGoals] => 12
            [totalAwayGoals] => 31
            [totalAwayAgainstGoals] => 11
        )

    [Team2] => Array
        (
            [totalHomeGoals] => 31
            [totalHomeAgainstGoals] => 25
            [totalAwayGoals] => 25
            [totalAwayAgainstGoals] => 27
        )

    [Team3] => Array
        (
            [totalHomeGoals] => 22
            [totalHomeAgainstGoals] => 21
            [totalAwayGoals] => 15
            [totalAwayAgainstGoals] => 38
        )
)
```

So now i want to make calculations for each possible match. To make it simple let's  say i want to add the AwayGoals to the Homegoals, so like this:

```
Team1 vs Team2 -> 48 + 25  
Team2 vs Team1 -> 31 + 31  
Team1 vs Team3 -> 48 + 15  
Team3 vs Team1 -> 22 + 31  
Team2 vs Team3 -> 31 + 15
```

etc
etc for all 12 possible matches

What direction should i look to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried two nested for-loops? Would that work for you?

Comment: @JonathanGagne I did, but because of my reputation it will not show (i'm getting a message that my upvote is recorded but will not show)

Comment: @Awesom-o Oh I see, thank you very much btw! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is my proposal.

First I fixed your array.

```
$teams = Array
(
    'Team1' => Array
    (
        'totalHomeGoals'        => 48,
        'totalHomeAgainstGoals' => 12,
        'totalAwayGoals'        => 31,
        'totalAwayAgainstGoals' => 11
    ),
    'Team2' => Array
    (
        'totalHomeGoals'        => 31,
        'totalHomeAgainstGoals' => 25,
        'totalAwayGoals'        => 25,
        'totalAwayAgainstGoals' => 27
    ),
    'Team3' => Array
    (
        'totalHomeGoals'        => 22,
        'totalHomeAgainstGoals' => 21,
        'totalAwayGoals'        => 15,
        'totalAwayAgainstGoals' => 38,
    )
);
```

Then I created a function that will provide unique team result and not. Here is what the code looks like.

```
function showResult($i, $j, $param1, $param2, $teams, $teamKeys) {
    echo $teamKeys[$i] . ' vs ' . $teamKeys[$j] . ' -> ' . $teams[$teamKeys[$i]][$param1] . ' + ' . $teams[$teamKeys[$j]][$param2] . '<br/>';
}

function getAllResult($teams, $param1, $param2, $unique=true) {
    $teamKeys = array_keys($teams);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($teams); $i++) {
        if(!$unique) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($teams); $j++) {
                showResult($i, $j, $param1, $param2, $teams, $teamKeys);
            }
        } else {
            for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($teams); $j++) {
                showResult($i, $j, $param1, $param2, $teams, $teamKeys);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how it works if you want to repeat the probability, such as Team1 VS Team2 and Team2 VS Team1.

```
getAllResult($teams, 'totalHomeGoals', 'totalAwayGoals', false);
```

Output:

```
Team1 vs Team1 -> 48 + 31
Team1 vs Team2 -> 48 + 25
Team1 vs Team3 -> 48 + 15
Team2 vs Team1 -> 31 + 31
Team2 vs Team2 -> 31 + 25
Team2 vs Team3 -> 31 + 15
Team3 vs Team1 -> 22 + 31
Team3 vs Team2 -> 22 + 25
Team3 vs Team3 -> 22 + 15
```

Here is how it works if you want to have only unique probabilities.

```
getAllResult($teams, 'totalHomeGoals', 'totalAwayGoals');
```

Output:

```
Team1 vs Team2 -> 48 + 25
Team1 vs Team3 -> 48 + 15
Team2 vs Team3 -> 31 + 15
```

Then you can change the attribute for whatever you would prefer.

Let me know if you have any question